# Generalized functions on a product of two manifolds

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, smooth-manifolds, schwartz-distributions, locally-convex-spaces, generalized-functions

Let $X,Y$ be smooth compact manifolds. Let $C^\infty(X)$ and $C^{-\infty}(X)$ denote the spaces of smooth and generalized functions on $X$ respectively. We have the obvious canonical linear map $$T\colon C^{-\infty}(X\times Y)\to Bil(C^\infty(X),C^\infty(Y)),$$
where the target is the space of continuous bilinear functionals $C^\infty(X)\times C^\infty(Y)\to \mathbb{C}$. By definition $(T\Phi)(f,g)=\Phi(f\otimes g)$.

It is well known that $T$ is isomorphism of vector spaces. **For which standard topologies on the source and the target $T$ is an isomorphism of topological vector spaces?**

For example let us choose on $C^{-\infty}(X\times Y)$ the strong topology, and on the target the topology given by seminorms
$$||B||_{K,L}:=\sup_{k\in K,l\in L}|B(k,l))|,$$
where $K\subset C^\infty(X), L\subset C^\infty(Y)$ are arbitrary bounded subset. Then $T$ will be a continuous map for these topologies. **But is $T$ a topological isomoprhism?**

Comment: This true and one of the manifold formulations of the celecbrated kernel

Comment: celebrated kernel theorem of L. Schwartz.  Primary references: Grothendieck's thesis and Schwartz' articles on vector-vaued distributions and smooth functions which are easy to trace.  Secondary: the books of F. Treves.

Answer (score 3):

$T$ is indeed a topological isomorphism. Indepently of the concrete situation, this can be shown by a suitable version of the closed graph theorem, e.g. the one of de Wilde: the domain has to be ultrabornological an the range should have a web (see, e.g., the book *Introduction to Functional Analysis* of Meise and Vogt, chapter 24). Here $T$ acts from the dual of the nuclear Frechet space $C^\infty(X\times Y)$ to $Bil(C^\infty(X),C^\infty(Y))\cong L(C^\infty(X),C^{-\infty}(Y))$. It follows e.g. from Grothendieck's work that both spaces are ultrabornological, and both spaces also have web. Therefore, one can apply the closed graph theorem fot $T$ and its inverse. (One can even show that the domain and range space are both isomorphic to $s'$, the space of slowly increasing sequences.)